# I created a sequence but I can't alter the increment number after that

Tags: oracle, sequence

Create sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE NEXT 
INCREMENT BY 2
START WITH 1000 
MINVALUE 10;
```

Alter sequence

```
alter SEQUENCE NEXT 
INCREMENT BY 3
START WITH 1000 
MINVALUE 10;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The starting value of a sequence can not be altered. Use:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE NEXT INCREMENT BY 3;
```